# AOL and outlook address book grabber

Tags: language-agnostic

how can i get the aol or outlook address books when the user inserts his username and password
I saw many programns that do it 
maybe someone has the source code?

I found a very nice one for yahoo gmail and hotmail

https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencontactsnet/

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the Outlook address books since they're on the user's machine - they would need to export to CSV and upload. There are [a lot of tutorials out there](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHMP_enUS291&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=asp.net+import+csv) for importing CSV files using ASP.NET.

It looks like you can't get AOL contacts either - according to [this article](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/yahoo_releases_address_book_api.php) they're the only major email provider that hasn't provided a public address book API.